# How to draw a fraction of a bezier curve with canvas?

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas, bezier, spline

Let's say I have a bezier curve produced from the following code:

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(50, 20);
ctx.quadraticCurveTo(230, 30, 50, 100);
ctx.stroke();
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

Is there a way to only draw, say, the last 90% of it?

For my application I want to "consume" the curve, and create an animation where a circle moves along the line path, eating the curve along the way.

The only thing I could think of was to instead of drawing the curve using the `quadraticCurveTo` function, to instead calculate a huge list of points manually through the following function:

```
t = 0.5; // given example value
x = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].x + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].x + t * t * p[2].x;
y = (1 - t) * (1 - t) * p[0].y + 2 * (1 - t) * t * p[1].y + t * t * p[2].y;
```

And then just do `moveTo` and `lineTo` for each of the 300 or so points.

But that has three issues:

1. It is computationally expensive
2. How do you determine how many points to calculate?
3. Won't it still be jagged unless you calculate thousands of points?

Is there a better way?

Comment: Are you willing to plug in your coordinates yourself, using some JS? If so: yeah, this is super easily doable and https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#splitting (which you can either implement yourself, or use something like [bezierjs](https://pomax.github.io/bezierjs/) will do for you) will almost trivially get you there. Except for the "90%" part. Because that's [very, very hard](https://pomax.github.io/bezierinfo/#tracing). However, if you have static coordinates, and you know your `t` value for 90% (give or take), it's trivial again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ctx.setLineDash([])` with `ctx.lineDashOffset`, that's the common way to simulate partial drawing of paths.

```js
const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');

animate();

function animate(){
    let i = 0;
    
    drawCurve(i);
    
    function drawCurve(start){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150); // initial width and height of canvas

        const line_len = 204; // to let the last part of curve stay

        ctx.setLineDash([1000]); // bigger than curve length    
        ctx.lineDashOffset = -start; // changing parameter
        
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(50, 20);
        ctx.quadraticCurveTo(230, 30, 50, 100);
        ctx.stroke();
        
        const anim_id = requestAnimationFrame(() => drawCurve(++start));
        if(start > line_len) cancelAnimationFrame(anim_id);
    }
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

It can be tricky to get length of the path in canvas. So I prefer to calculate it using hidden `SVG`. The `<path>` of it has empty `d` attribute. So I can assign our path string to it and `getTotalLength()` of it. Now we have length of your path and we can use those data to define `setLineDash` array properly, so the `path_len` (where to stop).

Also we can get the current position of path start by using path.getPointAtLength() method.

```js
animate();

function animate(){
    
    const path = document.querySelector('svg > path');
    const path_string = 'M 50 20 Q 230 30 50 100';
    path.setAttribute('d', path_string);

    const path_len = path.getTotalLength();

    const ctx = document.querySelector('canvas').getContext('2d');
    
    drawCurve(0);
    
    function drawCurve(start){
        ctx.clearRect(0,0,300,150); // initial width and height of canvas
        
        ctx.save();
        ctx.setLineDash([path_len + 1]); // bigger than curve length    
        ctx.lineDashOffset = -start; // changing parameter
        
        ctx.stroke(new Path2D(path_string));
        ctx.restore();
        
        const cur_pos = path.getPointAtLength(start - 7); // current position - (radius + 2)

        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.arc(cur_pos.x, cur_pos.y, 5, 0, 2*Math.PI, false); // radius = 5 (should be a constant)
        ctx.fill();
        
        const anim_id = requestAnimationFrame(() => drawCurve(++start));
        if(start > path_len) cancelAnimationFrame(anim_id);
    }
}
```

```html
<svg style="display:none">
    <path d=""></path>
</svg>
<canvas></canvas>
```

Comment: I see. Hmm, this is pretty good.. Very unfortunate that a hidden SVG is required. Well, I'll probably use this if no other way comes along. Thanks!

Comment: That's the only way to get the length of your path on fly. If the path doesn't change and you know the exact length of it - no need to use it. It's just a bonus))

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SVGGeometryElement/getPointAtLength - to get the new position by offset you also can use SVG. Unfortunately, `canvas` doesn't have two of these extremely useful methods.